# indefinite sums containing Kronecker Deltas in Mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, simplify

I want to simplify indefinite sums containing KroneckerDeltas, e.g:

$\sum_{k,k1,q} \beta(q) \beta(k+k1+q) \delta(k1+q)= \sum_{k,q} \beta(k)\beta(q)$

however

```
Sum[ β[q] β[k + q + k1] KroneckerDelta[k1 + q], k, k1, q] // FullSimplify
```

doesn't work, i.e I don't get

```
Sum[β[q] β[k ], k, q]
```

I also tried

```
c = FullSimplify[KroneckerDelta[q + k1] β[q] β[k + q + k1]]
Assuming[c != 0, FullSimplify[Sum[c, k, k1, q]]]
```

gives the the input as output

I have found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18235/simplification-of-double-symbolic-sums-containing-a-discretedelta-without-explic?rq=1) a custom `MyDiscreteDelta` function which also doesn't work.
Is there a way to achieve such simplifications?

Comment: @Bill you are right, I corrected it. I don't recall how I got the previous result. I was trying many things. `k, q, k1` are Reals. I don't know if that can help.

Comment: I thought maybe one can define a new function but I can't figure out how to.

Comment: @Bill `k,k1,q` are Reals but don't take actual numerical values. Your function seems to work fine if `k1,q` take specific values and `β` is known. I would like to achieve `Sum[ β[q] β[k + q + k1] KroneckerDelta[k1 + q], k, k1, q] -> Sum[β[q] β[k ], k, q]`

Comment: @Bill `Assuming[k1+q==0,expr=Simplify[β[q] β[k+q+k1] KroneckerDelta[k1+q]] ` does return  `Σ over k Σ over q β[k] β[q]`  but you have manually excluded the sum over `k1`.

Comment: `Sum[ β[q] β[k + q + k1] KroneckerDelta[k1 + q], k, k1, q]` to be equal to `Sum[β[q] β[k ], k, q]` as I state in the question.

Comment: I don't see a way to get what you are looking for.